# Getting padding exceptions even though i'm using padding imy algorithm

Tags: java, encryption, blowfish

I keep getting the exception "javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher" And I've google around a bit and found out that i needed to use this algorithm "Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding";" in both the encryption and decryption to make the padding since it has to be multiple of 8, but the problem still arises. I'm encrypting some data, then serializing it and then deserializing it and I'm starting to think its something wrong with the encryption? But everytime I encrypt I don't get any exceptions.

I've tried using the IVspec method, but since i'm using ECB i get the exception saying I shouldn't use that method. This is the code to decrypt the code

```
    try {

        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding"); // algoritm som används
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey); // väljer att man ska dekryptera

        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(encryptedData);

        int numberOfByteRead;
        CipherInputStream in = new CipherInputStream(fs, cipher);

        in.read(data);

        decryptedDataOut = cipher.doFinal(data); //enkrypterade datan blir dekrypterad
        in.close();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException  | IOException   e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And this is the code to encrypt and to serialize it
        Cipher cipher = null;

```
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm); // Krypterar med blowfish
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey); // krypterar
        out = cipher.doFinal(in.getBytes()); // krypterar datan i strängen in

    } catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException   e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try { // Skriver den krypterade datan till en ny fil med namnet på encryptedData


        FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(encryptedData);

        CipherOutputStream output = new CipherOutputStream(fs, cipher);
        output.write(out);
        output.flush();
        output.close();



        System.out.println("Encrypted \"" + data + "\" to file " + encryptedData);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're encrypting everything twice. Why is that?

Comment: I managed to solve the  problem, the problem was in the encryption. I somehow had managed to mess up some variables. Typical...